# Estimate for second difference method by Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $h=1/N$ and $x_i=ih, i=0,\dots,N.$

For a function $\phi:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ define the second difference by
$$D_x^2\phi(x_i):=\frac{\phi(x_{i+1})-2\phi(x_i)+\phi(x_{i-1})}{h^2},\quad i=1,\dots N-1.$$

If $\phi \in C^4(\bar{\Omega})$ then
$$|D_x^2 \phi(x_i)-\partial_x^2 \phi(x_i)|\le C_ch^2 |\phi|_{C^4(\bar{\Omega})}, \quad i=1,\dots,N-1,$$ where $C_c>0$ is a constant independent of $h,\phi,i.$

The proof of this just says by Taylor expansion. But I can't see how to obtain this bound by Taylor expansion. I would greatly appreciate some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a simpler error term using the mean value theorem with $x=x_i$ as constant and $h$ as variable,
\begin{align}
&\hspace{-3em}\frac{\phi(x+h)-2\phi(x)+\phi(x+h)-h^2\phi''(x)}{h^4}
\\[.5em]&=
\frac{\phi'(x+h_1)-\phi'(x-h_1)-2h_1\phi''(x)}{4h_1^3}
\\[.5em]&=
\frac{\phi''(x+h_2)+\phi''(x-h_2)-2\phi''(x)}{12h_2^2}
\\[.5em]&=
\frac{\phi'''(x+h_3)-\phi'''(x-h_3)}{12\cdot 2h_3}
\\[.5em]&=\frac{\phi^{(4)}(x+h_4)}{12}
\end{align}
with $h>h_1>h_2>h_3>|h_4|$.

Comment: How do you get the first equality using mean value theorem?

Comment: The extended mean value theorem states $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$. Here we have situations, except in the last step, with $f(a)=g(a)=0$, always $a=0$ and starting with $b=h$, $c=h_1$.

Comment: Wow never thought about this method thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor expansion we have $\phi(x\pm h)=\phi(x)\pm h\partial_x\phi(x) + \frac{h^2}{2}\partial_x^2 \phi(x) \pm \frac{h^3}{6}\partial_x^3 \phi(x)+\frac{h^4}{24}\partial_x^4 \phi(\xi^{\pm})$ with some $\xi^-\in[x-h,x]$ and $\xi^+\in [x,x+h]$ by Lagrange formula.

So, $\phi(x_{i+1})-2\phi(x_i)+\phi(x_{i-1})=h^2\partial_x^2\phi(x_i)+\frac{h^4}{24}(\partial_x^4 \phi(\xi^+)+\partial_x^4\phi(\xi^-)).$

Hence dividing by $h^2$ and subtracting $\partial_x^2\phi(x_i)$, we get the desired bound.

Comment: In the 4th order you should have $4!=24$.